# Automatically move to next page if page is idle

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing a jquery mobile app and what i want to achieve is this: when the page remains idle for 3 seconds it should automatically move from page1 to page2, when you are on page 2 and it still remains idle for 3 seconds it should move to page3 and so on and so fourth. Can someone help me with a a script.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page1</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">This is page 1</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">This is page 2</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">This is page 3</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;
<div data-role="page" id="page4">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 4</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">This is page 4</div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle to my page

http://jsfiddle.net/91wu20fr/

Comment: How do you define idle?

Comment: I see no JS on your fiddle. Have you built out the routing & navigation functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `setTimeout`:

```
var goToNextPage = setTimeout(function () {
  location.href = 'page2.html';
}, 3000);
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("mousemove keypress", function () {
    clearTimeout(goToNextPage);
    goToNextPage = setTimeout(function () {
      location.href = 'page2.html';
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

This script essentially resets the timer when the mouse moves or key is pressed. Since you are using a mobile, replace those two with what all events the user can fire, like scroll, touch, blah blah and this should work for you.

Comment: He's using jQuery Mobile... so "mousemove" & "keypress" probably won't do anything.

Comment: @Mottie Please see the bottom... Read fully and comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Mottie `Since you are using a mobile, replace those two with what all events the user can fire, like scroll, touch, blah blah and this should work for you.`

Comment: LOL that wasn't there when I added the comment

Comment: @Mottie When you add a comment, it will show `Edited just now`. Since it didn't show, I didn't make any edits after you have commented.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, with your script it only moves to page2. what of the subsequent ones?

Comment: @i_user You have to write the code for that! LoL. How do I know what all the other pages you have? `:)`